# looking for tree list view library

Tags: android

I want to develop an application which display information as tree view. Each leaf should contains a button.

Are there an android library which offer a tree view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this source http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/. Easy to change I guess.